# xPath, getting tabular data

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I have a HTML thus like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Email</th>
     <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Joe Bloggs</td>
     <td>joe@bloggs.com</td>
     <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>John Doe</td>
     <td>john@doe.com</td>
     <td>40</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Is there a way using xPath to get the first 2 columns, i.e the `Name` and `Email` fields?

I can get the table data using `$data = $xpath->query( '//table');` just unsure how to get only the first 2 columns.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the first two `td`'s:

```
//table/tr/td[position() <= 2]
```